# Is there a way to add styles in css or sass based on the post content?

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to add styles in css or sass based on the post content?

Answer (score 0):

Im using
https://github.com/jessegavin/jQuery-Chord-Transposer

Something is preventing the code I just added from running.

```html
    var textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

// directly converting the found 'a' elements into an Array,
// then iterating over that array with Array.prototype.forEach():
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('span.c'), 0).forEach(function(aEl) {
  // if the text of the aEl Node contains the text 'link1':
  if (aEl[textProp].indexOf('Am') > -1) {
    // we update its style:
 
    aEl.style.fontSize = '2em';
    
aEl.className = 'c foo';
    
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a thin layer of JS to add a CSS class to a parent element, which the css can check for.

For example, here is some code that makes the text color red if a post has a .category element with 'memes' in it

e.g.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .post.memes {
        color: 'red' 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article class="post">
      <p class="category">memes</p>
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum</p>
    </article>

    <script>
      const postElement = document.querySelector('.post');

      if (postElement) {
        const category = postElement.querySelector('.category');
        if (category && category.innerHTML == 'memes') {
          postElement.classList.add('memes');
        }
      }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```